# Running external programs from PowerShell results in error. Why?

Tags: windows-server-2003, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that starts several external programs and batch files. All of calls worked fine on my Windows XP/PowerShell 2.0 machine.

On a Windows Server 2003/PowerShell 1.0, however, several of those resulted in an error "ERROR: operable program or batch file." for some reason. Some worked. Most resulted in the error.

What am I likely doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason not to update your 2003 machines to PowerShell 2?

Comment: Yes. I cannot install software on the machines. I can only run scripts to configure one product on them.

Comment: FWIW - Based on this and other questions you've posted, I suggest you down-rev your local PoSH install (or build a virtual machine running v1) so you start getting consistent results.

Comment: Alas this is not possible. Company has very rigid rules and won't allow such changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess it's not related to XP/2K3 or v1/v2. Double-check your PATH and that the particular external programs actually exist on the Server system.

That error message seems to imply that the external program doesn't exist (or more likely, we just don't know where it is due to PATH differences).

Comment: I think the error message is the last few words of something like "<name> is not an operable program or batch file" so something is apparently found. The programs do exist and can be started from the command line outside the script.